# CSS/HTML Internet explorer image height: 100% of div

Tags: css, internet-explorer, html, height

I have built my website using div block.
I have one div with 70% height and in this div I want to put image with 100% height of this div.
In firefox, opera, chrome, it works perfectly but not in Internet Explorer.
Have you any ideas ?

Comment: What version of IE?  Can you post some code.

Comment: Have you set `html,body{height:100%;}` ?

Comment: Yes, I set html,body{height:100%;};

Comment: "Not working" is not a description of a problem, what happens instead of expected results? Please post the relevant code too...

Answer (score 0):

Nick Bull is right, but you'll need more than that. You can use background-size: cover to make sure it fills the whole background and doesn't repeat. Example pulled from css-tricks:

```
.your_div { 
  background: url(images/your_bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

Comment: in my website background works good but i have problem with image

Comment: Do you want the image to have 100% height and 100% width, or just 100% height?